# append something else before ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh

Im using this `ssh-copy-id` command but before I add the public key I would like to add some stuff like, new line and Name. For example:

```
new line    
#Name of the person
pub.key here ..asdadsdad
```

Because this is going through script with for loop on many servers how can I put this to go with it. For now I have this:

```
for i in $( cat file_servers ) do 
ssh-copy-id -i keyfile root@$i
```

etc. But I don't know how can I add new line and the "#name of the person" before the key is append at the last line.

Comment: Why don't edit public key file directly before run `ssh-copy-id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh-copy-id` basically copies the local `keyfile` (or `identity`, or public key) to the remote server, so you can just edit your `keyfile` and add what you want into it.

Edit your `keyfile` and add what you want:

```
#
# Name of the person
ssh-rsa  NF username@host
```

Now, when you do `ssh-copy-id -i keyfile <host>`, those lines will be appended to the remote server's `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Hey Alaa Ali, THANKS man, i did't know that i can modify the key like that this is excellent ! It works perfect. I  just see something but im guessing it count the new line that iv add. It shows me this line `Number of key(s) added: 3` I only tested with one key but im guessing it counts the lines that iv add ? or ?

Comment: Yeah, it's just blindly counting all the lines it appended, whether they're comments or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could add an inline substitution with sed, like this:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\nName of person\n/' $i
```

This substitutes the first line at the beginning of the file with a white line (\n), the name of the person, and a carriage return (\n).

This goes between the two lines of your script.

Comment: He wants to add that information to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the remote server he's going to copy the public keys to. Your command won't do that. `$i` is also holding the IP address of the servers.

Comment: Of course, you're right. I misunderstood due to the phrase (I quote) "but before I add the public key". My meaning was to add this information to the public key before sending over, but if I had paid more attention, I would have realized $i is for every remote server..